# Rails query using association - has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a model called User that has:

```
  has_many     :parent_relationships,
               :class_name            => "Relationship",
               :foreign_key           => :child_id,
               :dependent             => :destroy,
               :uniq => true
  has_many     :parents,
               :through               => :parent_relationships,
               :source                => :parent
```

So, I want to be able to find the Users who have at least one parent. Right now, if I fetch a particular user and I do `user.parents`, I get the list of parents, but how would I do that in a where clause?

My concern is that right now I am fetching like this:

```
User.where({:role => 'Teen'})
```

So, I want to find all the Users whose role is a Teen and who at least have a parent.  Also, and to make it more complicated, I have another association that I would like to take into account:

```
 has_and_belongs_to_many :notifications
```

And I would like to find those Users who has a notification which name attribute is "email".

Thanks

Comment: You're question is not quite clear - do you want to find *a* user with a parent, via `User.find(...)`? In which case, which one? Or *all* users that have at least one parent, via `User.where(...)`?

Comment: All users which have at least one parent. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join should do it:

```
User.joins(:parents).uniq
```

Since this creates an `INNER JOIN`, it will only return the records with parents. The `uniq` removes duplicate records that may be returned by the join.

**EDIT**:

Your method chaining could work something like this:

```
User.includes(:notifications).joins(:parents).where(:role => "Teen").where("notifications.name = 'email'")
```

Comment: Thilo, I have edited my question because I believe that my concern is how to chain this query with another that I already have.

Comment: You should be able to do that with the join, simply append your `where` clause.